# Spore space stage mission problem

Tags: spore

I found an old CD with spore on it, and I installed it. However once reaching the space stage, after I finish all of the missions, I am left with this screen:

[image]

There are no more choices, no way to continue the game. What's the problem?

Comment: I suspect this is probably due to Spore's servers being down for the count; I recall Spore was a heavily community based adventure, so a lot of the stuff probably existed on the server alone.

Comment: @Frank Were the servers recently taken down? I just played this a few months ago through Steam, and I didn't have any problems. Also, the only thing the game really needed the servers for was for community creations (aliens, buildings, vehicles, etc.)... but the base game has a number of defaults that don't need the servers, so that shouldn't be a problem. I've definitely finished the game without any internet connection at all in one of my earlier playthroughs.

Comment: The space stage is an open sandbox so it's not supposed to be entirely mission directed. You might have just simply run of out missions for now.  You should still be able to continue playing the game by doing whatever you want.

Comment: What? Someone edited my post, i finished just 3-4 missions, not all of them.